# What is the difference between やきもち and 嫉妬?

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between やきもち and 嫉妬? Both words translate to "jealousy", but is there a difference in the details of the definition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

やきもち is used exclusively in contexts where someone you care for is interested in someone/something else and you feel you are not getting enough attention/love. Most of the time, this is used in romance-related contexts. Etymologically, it's a pun on [妬【や】く](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%A6%AC%E3%81%8F) and 焼【や】き餅【もち】. The word derived from the resemblance of balloon-like inflated cheeks and baked *mochi*. Thus, やきもち tends to refer to a temporary and not-so-serious jealousy, and it's often seen as a cute behavior. See [these image search results](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search?p=%E3%82%84%E3%81%8D%E3%82%82%E3%81%A1).

On the other hand, I think 嫉妬【しっと】 is almost the same as English "jealousy". It includes both mild ones and very dreadful ones, and it can be about anything (e.g., someone's talent). For example, you can say 彼【かれ】の才能【さいのう】に嫉妬【しっと】させられます referring to a gifted baseball player, but you cannot say 彼【かれ】の才能【さいのう】にやきもちを焼【や】かされます in the same context.

Comment: Yahoo! Japan isn't available anymore in Europe and UK, so anyone in those areas can't see your link; here's a search in Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%82%84%E3%81%8D%E3%82%82%E3%81%A1&tbm=isch

Comment: @Mauro, seriously? Is Yahoo! Japan actively blocking access from EU and UK IP addresses? How disappointing.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi unfortunately yes, if you're interested here's the notice: https://i.imgur.com/KjjuqWF.png